# Need to assign different values to letters and non-letters in a sentence

Tags: python

Need to assign a value 1-26 to letters of the alphabet (i.e., a = 1, b = 2, etc.) and -1 to anything else in a sentence and then add up the values.

Currently have:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase 

s = "Isn't it amazing?"
s = s.lower() #upper case version should have the same value as lower

letters = {letter: str(i) for i, letter in enumerate(ascii_lowercase, start=1)} 
answer = [letters[char] for char in s if char in letters elif char not in letters -1]

for i in range(0, len(answer)): 
    answer[i] = int(answer[i]) 
sum(answer)
```

Desired return for sentence *s* is 158. Is there a way to use else in list comprehension?

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary provides a specific function for your use case: [dict.get](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), from the documentation:

> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If
>   default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never
>   raises a KeyError.

**Code**

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

s = "Isn't it amazing?"
s = s.lower()  # upper case version should have the same value as lower

letters = {letter: i for i, letter in enumerate(ascii_lowercase, start=1)}
answer = [letters.get(char, -1) for char in s]

print(sum(answer))
```

**Output**

```
158
```

Also, notice that if plan to use the integer value of the enumerate you don't need to transform it into a string. If you insist in using a [ternary operator](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator), you could do it like this:

```
answer = [letters[char] if char in letters else -1 for char in s]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` is in the wrong position. Also, `ord` is the usual way to translate a character to a number (subtract the value for `'a'`, adding one, to get 1-based numbers).

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

s = "Isn't it amazing?"
s = s.lower() #upper case version should have the same value as lower
vals = [ord(ch)-ord('a')+1  if ch in ascii_lowercase else -1 for ch in s ]
answer = sum(vals)
print(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can 1st convert the string into bytes and use the ascii byte value like below

```py
s = "Isn't it amazing?"
s = s.lower()
sum([(b-96) if b>=97 and b<=122 else -1 for b in bytes(s, "ascii") ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering char code of starting letter `"a"` as constant subtraction number:

```
sub_num = ord('a') - 1
answer = [ord(c) - sub_num if c.isalpha() else -1 for c in s]
print(sum(answer))    # 158
```